# TraceId missing when logging @SqsListener

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-logback

In my spring boot project, TraceId missing only inside @SqsListener annotated method.
I have used `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` for logging and logback configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey even it was not working for 1.2.5 version of sleuth

so i made some changes - these are manual changes for tracer and span id

```
@SqsListener(value = "test", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void process(final String message) {

String traceId = MDC.get("traceId");
Span span = tracer.createSpan(traceId);
LOGGER.info("Request for : " + message);
try {
    // System user and your working stuff
    tracer.close();
    return;
} catch (Exception e) {
    ThreadLocalUtil.resetRequestInitiator();
    LOGGER.error("Exception in message", e);
}

throw new ErrorProcessSQS("Exception in message");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Which sleuth version are you using? They removed SQS support since 3.0 release. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1876.

This repo can be helpful in implementing putting traces into SQS messages but getting them from the message and injecting into MDC you need to implement on your own.

Comment: I have used version: '2.2.8.RELEASE'